# Is it possible to accessTypescript Classes in .Net Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

I have some TypeScript classes that where originaly written inside of my nest.js Application.

Now I want to use these TypeScript classes/methods inside my .Net Core Web Application- So I don't need to write the same classes/functions in C# again :-)

I know that it's possible to use Javascript in C# with **aspnet/JavaScriptService [Archived] (Obsolete)**

Is there a similar way to access my TypeScript code f**rom C# (API backend-controller)?**
It should be run on Window Microsoft **Internet Information Service - IIS.**

Thanks a lot for any answer.

Comment: It will probably be less effort for you to recreate the classes and methods in C# than it will be to use your TypeScript classes.

Comment: @John Do you have anny succestion or a solution for this problem? :-)